# Google visualization table not displaying with getJSON call to remote server

Tags: php, mysql, jsonp, getjson, remote-server

I've search the internet for days for what I thought would be a fairly common request, i.e., to populate a google visualization table on a local server using data (JSON Data Table) from a remote server.

I found a coding example on the google code playground (http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#json_data_table) which helped me get started. This example works great for hard-coding the table entries directly into your html file.

Rather than hard-coding the values I would like to populate the local google visualization table with a JSONP request from a remote server.  Here's the contents of my php file which resides on a remote server:

```
<?php
//connect to mysql database using authentication credentials 
require_once( "inc/<connection file>.inc" );

// Query table
$sql="select id, address from historical_sales order by id";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql); 

$table = array();

$table['cols'] = array(
    array(id => "id", label => "ID", type => "string"),
    array(id => "address", label => "Address", type => "string")
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $temp = array();
    $temp[] = array("v" => $r["id"]);
    $temp[] = array("v" => $r["address"]); 

    $rows[] = array("c" => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);

header('Content-type: application/json');

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $jsonTable . ')'; 
?>
```

The output from this file is as follows:

({"cols":[{"id":"id","label":"ID","type":"string"},{"id":"address","label":"Address","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"355 W Honeysuckle Dr"}]},{"c":[{"v":"2"},{"v":"1688 W Yosemite Pl"}]},{"c":[{"v":"3"},{"v":"3800 S Cantabria Cir A-1001"}]},{"c":[{"v":"4"},{"v":"3560 S Hollyhock Pl"}]},{"c":[{"v":"5"},{"v":"1645 W Lantana Ct"}]}]})

My HTML file contains the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                                               
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    $.getJSON("http://mhsw.com/realestate/jsonp-xs.php?callback=?", {},function (jdata)
    {var JSONObject = jdata;
         document.getElementById("jid_label").innerHTML=JSONObject.cols[0].label;
         document.getElementById("jaddress_label").innerHTML=JSONObject.cols[1].label;
    });
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONObject, 0.6);
// Create and draw the visualization.
visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));

visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true});
                                                                          }                                                                          
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
});

</script><div id="table"></div>
<p>
ID: <span id="jid_label"></span><br />
Address: <span id="jaddress_label"></span><br />
</p>
```

I'm fairly certain the JSON Data is being received by the callback function within the HTML file, as I'm getting the ID and Address labels to appear, however, the google visualization table does not display.  Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, sometimes it just helps to talk through your coding problems … I just now realized to solve this issue all I had to do was to move three lines of code in the HTML file up into the getJSON function area.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the new HTML file which solves the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                                               
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table']});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function()
{
    function drawVisualization() 
    {
        // Create and populate the data table.
        $.getJSON("http://mhsw.com/realestate/jsonp-xs.php?callback=?", {},function (jdata)
        {
            var JSONObject = jdata;
            document.getElementById("jid_label").innerHTML=JSONObject.cols[0].label;
            document.getElementById("jaddress_label").innerHTML=JSONObject.cols[1].label;
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(JSONObject, 0.6);

            // Create and draw the visualization.
            visualization = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table'));
            visualization.draw(data, {'allowHtml': true});
        });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
});

</script><div id="table"></div>
<p>
ID: <span id="jid_label"></span><br />
Address: <span id="jaddress_label"></span><br />
</p>
```